# Fetching the charities using the global giving API using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, react-props

I'm using global giving API to make a charity finder app.

I have two dropdowns and a search button in the `CharityFinderPage.js` component. Now on clicking the search button, I want to fetch the charities using the `themeId`. The endpoint is `https://api.globalgiving.org/api/public/projectservice/themes/{themeId}/projects`

I know that on `handleClick` I should fetch the charities, but how do I get the value of `themeId` in the `handleClick` of `CharityFinderPage.js` component.

What I want is to show a new card component when the button clicks like showing a charity card with the fields populated on it from the data of the API, but first I need to be able to get the data from the API, then I can render a new component.

Here's the code:

**CharityFinderPage.js**

```js
const CharityFinderPage = () => {

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("inside handleclick")
  }

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <h1>Charity Finder ❤️</h1>
      <h3>Search for charity</h3>
      <h4>
        Filter charities by personal search conditions. Use the dropdown below
        to see charities matching your criteria.
      </h4>

      <Themes />
      <Regions />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Search</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CharityFinderPage
```

**Themes.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
const url = `https://api.globalgiving.org/api/public/projectservice/themes.json?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_api_key}`

const Themes = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState("")
  const [themes, setThemes] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchThemes = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true)
        const result = await axios.get(url)
        setThemes(result.data.themes.theme)
        setIsLoading(false)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    fetchThemes()
  }, [])

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("inside handleChange", event.target.value)
    setSelectValue(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <h4>Loading......</h4>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <label>Select theme: </label>
          <select onChange={handleChange} value={selectValue}>
            {themes.map((theme, id) => {
              return <option key={id}>{theme.name}</option> //{id} is the `themeId`
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Themes
```

`Regions` component is exactly similar to `Themes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing that you need to do here is called lifting the state up.

You need to move your states of theme component to CharityFinder component

I am lifting only selectedValue because that is all that you need

CharityFinderPage.js

```
const CharityFinderPage = () => {

  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState("")



  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(`inside handleclick with ${selectValue}`)
  }

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <h1>Charity Finder ❤️</h1>
      <h3>Search for charity</h3>
      <h4>
        Filter charities by personal search conditions. Use the dropdown below
        to see charities matching your criteria.
      </h4>

// you can pass the setSelectValue as prop to Themes component
      <Themes setSelectValue={setSelectValue} selectValue={selectValue} />
      <Regions />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Search</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CharityFinderPage
```

Theme.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
const url = `https://api.globalgiving.org/api/public/projectservice/themes.json?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_api_key}`

const Themes = ({ selectValue, setSelectValue }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [themes, setThemes] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchThemes = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true)
        const result = await axios.get(url)
        setThemes(result.data.themes.theme)
        setIsLoading(false)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    fetchThemes()
  }, [])

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("inside handleChange", event.target.value)
    setSelectValue(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <h4>Loading......</h4>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <label>Select theme: </label>
          <select onChange={handleChange} value={selectValue}>
            {themes.map((theme, id) => {
              return <option key={id}>{theme.name}</option> //{id} is the `themeId`
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Themes
```

Comment: You can read more about it in official docs https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: it says `selectValue` is not defined, in `Themes` component in this line `value={selectValue}>`. Also saying `props is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
const CharityFinderPage = () => {
  const [themeId, setThemeId] = useState();
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("inside handleclick")
    // make call to endpoint with themeId
  }

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <h1>Charity Finder ❤️</h1>
      <h3>Search for charity</h3>
      <h4>
        Filter charities by personal search conditions. Use the dropdown below
        to see charities matching your criteria.
      </h4>

      <Themes setThemeId={setThemeId} />
      <Regions />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Search</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CharityFinderPage
```

Then in Themes.js:

```
...

const handleChange = (event) => {
  console.log("inside handleChange", event.target.value)
  props.setThemeId(event.target.value);
  setSelectValue(event.target.value)
}

...
```